# Is Node.js suited for compute intensive web services

Tags: multithreading, apache, node.js, iis, computation

I am going to create a set of web services that include very compute intensive code. The calculations can run from 1/2 a second to 20 seconds. The computations exist in C code.

I would probably not have more than 20 simultaneous web service requests of which only a couple would be the longer running calculations.

My understanding is that node.js runs in a single thread so I would have to write a node.js addon which would interface to my C code. The C code would then have to execute in its own thread. I would use the thread pools provided by node.js to run these computations asynchronously. I would run this on a multi-core machine to maximize performance.

Does the architecture that I described sound correct and is node.js suited to do this? Would Apache or IIS be better at an application like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a native C program, and have node execute the binary, and callback upon completion. I think there are a couple methods, here is an example of `child_process.exec(command, [options], callback)` copied from [nodejitsu](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/child-processes/how-to-spawn-a-child-process):

```
var childProcess = require('child_process'),
     ls;

 ls = childProcess.exec('ls -l', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
   if (error) {
     console.log(error.stack);
     console.log('Error code: '+error.code);
     console.log('Signal received: '+error.signal);
   }
   console.log('Child Process STDOUT: '+stdout);
   console.log('Child Process STDERR: '+stderr);
 });

 ls.on('exit', function (code) {
   console.log('Child process exited with exit code '+code);
 });
```

*edit*
If you need to pass input to your process after starting it, use [`child_process.spawn`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) instead.

Node can handle apache's tasks well; I use [express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express) to host files and dynamic pages; my application logic is javascript code that is called by Express when particular HTTP requests are made to particular routes.

You might bog your machine down unless you cap simultaneous computations. I have no knowledge or comment on thread pools.  [caolan/async](https://github.com/caolan/async#queueworker-concurrency) can help manage concurrent computations (and other control flow tasks.)

Comment: This would seem to work only with a standalone executable? I really need to be able to call a function and pass in and get back complex data. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: i think that's possible, I don't have any further knowledge about it though - gl!